# Apns push server errors

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We started getting 400 errors last night with the following reasons with our voip pushes on apns.

'BadDeviceToken'
  'TopicDisallowed' 
  'Unregistered'

Has anyone else experience this?

Comment: How did you resolve this? Any help would really help me

Answer (score 0):

400 Bad Request is a general error. This error occurs when the cloud service sends a notification request with a bad XML document or malformed notification URI and also make sure that XML payloads contain UTF-8 encoded text, and that raw notifications are in base64 with the Content-Type header set to application/octet-stream.